# Android Studio complains of expression being null even after check

Tags: android, android-studio, null, warnings

I have the following line of code in `onCreateView()` method of my `Fragment`. It warns me that the expression to `createPinPresenter.setLoginResult()` can be `null`.

[image: expression might be null warning]

So I ask AS to generate the `null` check and it does this.

[image: expression might be null even after surrounding with if]

Even after the auto generated code, AS still complains the same expression being `null`. It obviously cannot be `null` inside the check.

Am I missing something obvious here or is this a bug?

Edit: I'm using AS version 2.2.3

Comment: More likely not a bug, just something not smart enough to read the code above it and see the null check.  Its trivial to see if a function can return null, its hard to parse code and see if its actually checked.

Comment: @GabeSechan But I've seen AS wave off warnings (other than nulls maybe) once appropriate checks are done. Shouldn't it do the same for this? For example, it asks to convert `assert expression != null` to `if(BuildConfig.DEBUG && expression) {throw new AssertionError();}`

Comment: Even that's easier than what you're expecting it to do-  you're not looking for it to parse an entire function and analyze the context, you're looking at a simple one line rule-  if calling assert(blah), convert to if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) blah.  What you want is more of a feature request than a bug.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct, how does AS know if, for example, getParcelable() will return the same value? it is just a syntactic control, not a semantic control.
A function could return, for example, `null` if the number of times it has been called is odd: in that case the warning is correct.

Think this:

```
if (getNextValue() != null)
   value = getNextValue();
```

If `getNextValue()` increments an index, at the end of an array it could return `null`: the error is pretty obvious, and it's actually what the control tries to prevent in your code.

The only solution is to store the result of `getParcelable(KEY_LOGIN_RESULT)` in a temporary variable, in that case AS will correctly manage it.

And of course... the fact that this is an autogenerated code, is actually a bug, I think, of the autogeneration, that is less smart than the control.

Comment: Yes I agree that the auto generation is a bug. I've opened an issue at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=233192 Let's see what the developers have to say.

Comment: I believe nothing. It's not AS's to create local variables, it would be an additional source of possible errors in the code.

Comment: AS does create variables when we perform 'extract variable' refactoring. Also these variables are unique in scope.

Comment: But in that case you explicity request AS to create new variables. Anyway, I didn't know that :)